# Confused about methods to speed up video

Tags: video, video-editor, framerate, time-lapse

I have some CCTV recordings that I would like to speed up (like a timelapse) and I am confused about which method to use. I tested Avidemux and VSDC Video Editor and they both speed up videos in different ways:
•The "Change FPS" filter in Avidemux appears to speed up a video by cramming in more frames per second.
•The "Speed (%)" setting in VSDC appears to speed up the video by discarding extra frames, but keeps the final frame rate the same as the original file.

Is one method better or preferred over the other? Are there any major pros/cons for each method?

Here are the "MediaInfo" results for an MP4 test file I sped up by 10x using both methods:

**ORIGINAL FILE**
FILE SIZE/LENGTH: 37 MiB / 1 min 7 s 134 ms [00:01:07.134 (00:01:07:03)]
VIDEO BITRATE/FPS: 4 678 kb/s () @ **15 FPS** (Constant) **[Total Frames: 1008]**
SIZE/ASPECT: 1920px * 1080px @ 16:9 (1.778) Aspect Ratio
VIDEO FORMAT: AVC (Advanced Video Codec) / High@L4 / CABAC / 1 Ref Frames
VIDEO CODEC: video/H264 / Advanced Video Coding / 8 bits / Progressive Scan

**VSDC (Changed speed from 100% to 1000%  to speed up by 10x)**
FILE SIZE/LENGTH: 14 MiB / 6 s 734 ms [00:00:06.734 (00:00:06:11)]
VVIDEO BITRATE/FPS: 17.0 Mb/s () @ **15 FPS** (Constant) **[Total Frames: 101]**
SIZE/ASPECT: 1920px * 1080px @ 16:9 (1.778) Aspect Ratio
VIDEO FORMAT: AVC (Advanced Video Codec) / High@L5.1 / CABAC / 3 Ref Frames
VIDEO CODEC: video/H264 / Advanced Video Coding / 8 bits / Progressive Scan

**AVIDEMUX (Changed FPS from 15 to 150 to speed up by 10x)**
FILE SIZE/LENGTH: 17 MiB / 6 s 727 ms [00:00:06.727 (00:00:06::9)]
VIDEO BITRATE/FPS: 20.0 Mb/s () @ **150 FPS** (Constant) **[Total Frames: 1009]**
SIZE/ASPECT: 1920px * 1080px @ 16:9 (1.778) Aspect Ratio
VIDEO FORMAT: AVC (Advanced Video Codec) / High@L5.2 / CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
VIDEO CODEC: video/H264 / Advanced Video Coding / 8 bits / Progressive Scan

Comment: without seeing the videos, it should just boil down to personal preference. Typically I would do it with percent change but the other way by changing fps should make it smoother. basically cant tell without seeing the videos so just choose the one that best fits

Comment: I've since come to learn about one downside to increasing the fps to values above 60. Apparently lots of video players can't smoothly process more than 60fps during playback.